# Одновременная валидация имени и фамилии

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Есть модель в которой определяю имя и фамилию

```
string Name { get; set; }

string Surname { get; set; }
```

Сейчас у меня есть валидация которая проверяет введенное имя на Грузинском или на английском, если пользователь вводит что-то другое Regex делает своё дело.
Что делать если пользователь вводит имя на английском а фамилию на грузинском, тогда regex молчит.
Как мне это исправить ?

[RegularExpression("(^[a-zA-Z]+$)|(^[ა-ჰ]+$)")]

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, код валидации.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1 - "Additional fields"

Comment: @Igor Ответы в ответы.